# Is it possible to tell if a Macbook hard drive was booted internally versus externally (usb, firewire, etc.)?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, startup, external-disk, logs

Is it possible to tell from system.log or other logs whether a macbook pro hard drive was booted internally or taken out and booted externally (from USB, for example) ? I'm thinking the "BSD root" or "Got boot device" entries could be relevant, but I'm not sure.  I've shown an example log below.

Thanks !

*** EDIT: not sure why someone downvoted this - this is a good and relevant question.**

```
Mar 29 15:41:55 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1434483715 0
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.awdd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.callhistory.asl.conf" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.cloudd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.clouddocs" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.commerce.asl" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.CoreDuetAdmissionControl" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.eventmonitor" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.family.asl" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.ical" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.icloud.FindMyDevice" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.iokit.power" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.mail" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.networking.symptoms" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:26 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.sandbox.telemetry" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.secinitd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 29 15:42:26 --- last message repeated 6 times ---
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: vm_page_bootstrap: 879991 free pages and 94857 wired pages
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: kext submap [0xffffff7f80a00000 - 0xffffff8000000000], kernel text [0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff8000a00000]
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: zone leak detection enabled
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: "vm_compressor_mode" is 4
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: multiq scheduler config: deep-drain 0, urgent first 1, depth limit 4, band limit 127, sanity check 0
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: standard background quantum is 2500 us
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: mig_table_max_displ = 13
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=0 LocalApicId=0 Enabled
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=1 LocalApicId=1 Enabled
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for TMSafetyNet
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Safety net for Time Machine (TMSafetyNet)
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for AMFI
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Apple Mobile File Integrity (AMFI)
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Sandbox
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Seatbelt sandbox policy (Sandbox)
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Quarantine
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Quarantine policy (Quarantine)
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: MAC Framework successfully initialized
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: using 16384 buffer headers and 10240 cluster IO buffer headers
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool): Unknown key for string: SHAuthorizationRight
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: AppleKeyStore starting (BUILT: Mar 23 2015 11:37:46)
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: IOAPIC: Version 0x11 Vectors 64:87
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: ACPI: sleep states S3 S4 S5
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: pci (build 11:38:56 Mar 23 2015), flags 0xe3000, pfm64 (36 cpu) 0xf80000000, 0x80000000
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: (built 11:31:44 Mar 23 2015) initialization complete
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: console relocated to 0xf80010000
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 6, devices 18 ]
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: NVEthernet::start - Built Mar 23 2015 11:36:34
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: FireWire (OHCI) Lucent ID 5901 built-in now active, GUID 00264afffe0761ee; max speed s800.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000009833 0x5ac 0x8403 0x9833, 2
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: mcache: 2 CPU(s), 64 bytes CPU cache line size
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: mbinit: done [64 MB total pool size, (42/21) split]
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: rooting via boot-uuid from /chosen: JF8A7F5C-10BA-35F4-89BD-B35F5436ED0G
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting on <dict ID="0"><key>IOProviderClass</key><string ID="1">IOResources</string><key>IOResourceMatch</key><string ID="2">boot-uuid-media</string></dict>
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib kmod start
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless kmod start
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib load succeeded
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless load succeeded
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient: ready
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: BTCOEXIST off 
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: BRCM tunables:
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: pullmode[1] txringsize[  256] txsendqsize[1024] reapmin[   32] reapcount[  128]
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: Got boot device = IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SATA@B/AppleMCP79AHCI/PRT0@0/IOAHCIDevice@0/AppleAHCIDiskDriver/IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice/IOBlockStorageDriver/FUJITSU MJA2250BH FFS G1 Media/IOGUIDPartitionScheme/Customer@2
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: BSD root: disk0s2, major 1, minor 2
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Macintosh HD on device root_device
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: VM Swap Subsystem is ON
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx): The TimeOut key is no longer respected. It never did anything anyway.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.alf): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.audio.coreaudiod): Unknown key for array: seatbelt-profiles
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.auditd): The TimeOut key is no longer respected. It never did anything anyway.
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost hidd[93]: void __IOHIDPlugInLoadBundles(): Loaded 0 HID plugins
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost watchdogd[54]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(    wd_watchdog_open) - IOIteratorNext failed (kr=0)
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost watchdogd[54]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(      wd_daemon_init) - could not initialize the hardware watchdog
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.autofsd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost watchdogd[54]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(                main) - cannot initialize the watchdog service
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost hidd[93]: IOHIDService compatibility thread running at priority 63 and schedule 2.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.backupd-status): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost iconservicesagent[61]: iconservicesagent launched.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.backupd.status.xpc): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper): The TimeOut key is no longer respected. It never did anything anyway.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cmio.AVCAssistant): ThrottleInterval set to zero. You're not that important. Ignoring.
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost watchdogd[99]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(    wd_watchdog_open) - IOIteratorNext failed (kr=0)
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost watchdogd[99]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(      wd_daemon_init) - could not initialize the hardware watchdog
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost watchdogd[99]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(                main) - cannot initialize the watchdog service
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost com.apple.SecurityServer[76]: Session 100000 created
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cmio.IIDCVideoAssistant): ThrottleInterval set to zero. You're not that important. Ignoring.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cmio.VDCAssistant): ThrottleInterval set to zero. You're not that important. Ignoring.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.configd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CoreRAID): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CoreRAID): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar 29 15:42:08 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.installd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd): Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Interface::efiNVRAMPublished():  
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost kernel[0]: bpfAttach len 64 dlt 12
Mar 29 15:42:22 localhost wirelessproxd[70]: updateScanner - central is not powered on: 0
Mar 29 15:42:23 localhost iconservicesagent[61]: Starting service with cache path: /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.iconservices
Mar 29 15:42:25 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.avast.daemon): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar 29 15:42:25 localhost syslog[147]: ChmodBPF: Forcing creation and setting permissions for /dev/bpf*
Mar 29 15:42:25 localhost powerd[50]: Activity changes from 0xffff to 0x0. Assertions:1 HidState:0
Mar 29 15:42:25 localhost com.apple.SecurityServer[76]: Entering service
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: IOGraphics flags 0x43
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x8213 FirmwareVersion - 0x0208
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0x5000 ****
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: **** [BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- Completed (matched on Device) -- 0x5000 ****
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: NVDAStartup: Official
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: NVDANV50HAL loaded and registered
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][staticBluetoothTransportShowsUp] -- Received Bluetooth Controller register service notification -- 0x5000 
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][start] -- completed
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHCIController][ProcessBluetoothTransportShowsUpActionWL] -- Connected to the transport successfully -- 0xfb00 -- 0x1800 -- 0x5000 ****
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost opendirectoryd[69]: BUG in libdispatch: 14D136 - 2004 - 0x5
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost distnoted[97]: # distnote server daemon  absolute time: 32.520141728   civil time: Tue     Mar 29 15:42:26 2015   pid: 97 uid: 241  root: yes
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost hidd[93]: ____IOHIDSessionScheduleAsync_block_invoke: thread_id=0x105e76000
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost hidd[93]: HID Session async scheduling initiated.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost hidd[93]: HID Session async root queue running at priority 63 and schedule 2.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost hidd[93]: HID Session async scheduling complete.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost hidd[93]: Successfully opened the IOHIDSession
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost thermald[46]: Waiting for OSTT support notification
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost com.apple.usbmuxd[75]: usbmuxd-344.6 on Mar 16 2015 at 23:31:17, running 64 bit
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting for DSMOS...
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: Previous shutdown cause: 5
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost kernel[0]: DSMOS has arrived
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost loginwindow[89]: Login Window Application Started
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Service "com.apple.ManagedClient.startup" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.ManagedClient.agent" from owner: com.apple.ManagedClient
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost digest-service[176]: label: default
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost digest-service[176]:  dbname: od:/Local/Default
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost digest-service[176]:  mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost digest-service[176]:  acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost UserEventAgent[41]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Inactive
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost UserEventAgent[41]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost com.avast.daemon[144]: Starting daemon.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost systemkeychain[158]: done file: /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.done
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.appkit.xpc.sandboxedServiceRunner): The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.lakitu): The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.accounts.dom): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost iconservicesd[60]: iconservicesd launched.
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost iconservicesd[60]: Cache path: /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
Mar 29 15:42:26 localhost configd[49]: preference: no sharing preferences
Mar 29 15:42:27 localhost kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
Mar 29 15:42:27 localhost configd[49]: [bootp_transmit.c:213] bootp_transmit(): bpf_write(en0) failed: Network is down (50)
Mar 29 15:42:27 localhost configd[49]: DHCP en0: INIT transmit failed
Mar 29 15:42:27 localhost kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
Mar 29 15:42:27 localhost secinitd[174]: UID[0]: cache loaded: /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.app-sandbox-cache.plist
```

Comment: Re-reading your question, it seems to me you're asking if you could find out if someone took the drive out of your MacBook, accessed it, and put it back. The answer is definitely 'no'. That said, about 20 lines from the bottom (again, phone, sorry) there is an entry saying "login window started". This means the Mac came all the way up to the graphical environment that time, and it didn't look like much happened after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be a qualified [yes](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6430538?start=0&tstart=0). A post in the Apple discussions link says that there would be firmware logs (note Target Disk Mode is activated in the EFI before the OS loads) in /var/log/system.log:

```
kernel: hfs: mounted YourDiskName on device  diskXsX
```

Note this looks like a kernel log to me, so I'm not sure I believe it, but it may well be the firmware kernel mounting the drive (something has to).

As dwbrecovery points out (the user who suggested checking the logs), anyone who boots your Mac in target disk mode has unfettered access to your data. They could edit logs, make changes, and change time stamps to it would be impossible to know they were there.

Comment: @catmac, While theoretically possible to enable root from TDM, there would be much easier ways if a person had physical access to a machine ([single user mode](securemac.com/macosxsingleuser.php)). I didn't bother to look at the logs (I'm on my phone), anyone taking the time with the skills and motive to do what you describe would know how to hide their tracks very well.

Comment: @catmac, if you a really concerned about physical security (that people may gain access to your Mac while you are not with it), I can suggest two things, use an [EFI password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455), and enable [FileVault](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault). More importantly, keep your Mac with you. [Physical access is root access](http://useopensource.blogspot.com/2008/07/reminder-physical-access-root-access.html?m=1)

Comment: I did that recently, thanks for the advice. Just trying to analyze/investigate this specific incident to get a better idea of what happened.

Comment: @catmac, favorited. I'll take a look tomorrow.